Help with integrating Reinforcement learning in Gazebo with ROS
For a project I'm working on, I need to design a robotic hand (2 fingers and 1 thumb) that can grasp a cup detected using object detection. I want to use reinforcement learning so the hand can 'learn' the correct grip strenth. I want to use the real-time data from the pressure sensors I'm attaching to the tips of the 'fingers' and 'thumb' for the hand to learn the best grip for grasping each object. I am trying to model and simulate everything before building anything IRL.
In my research, OpenAI gym could be used for this, however, I'm confused if it is supported for the newest version of gazebo with ROS or ROS2. Can someone clarify what version is compatible and if I should use this software for this application?
Thanks in advance, I'm a bit lost with how to approach this. If anyone has done a similar project please let me know
